# RTNETLINK answers: No such process

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

I am trying to delete my default gateway  using ip -6 route .my ifconfig out put is

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:0c:ff:06  
          inet addr:192.168.2.230  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8::55c8:fca7:f47b:94c2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::dacb:8aff:fe0c:ff06/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:260289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:56489286 (56.4 MB)  TX bytes:4967963 (4.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1263 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1263 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:188712 (188.7 KB)  TX bytes:188712 (188.7 KB)
```

and ip -6 route output is

```
ip -6 route
2001:db8::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

when i am trying to remove 2001:db8::/64 .i am geting error no such process

root@manu-ThinkCentre-E73:/RnD# ip -6 route del 2001:db8::55c8:fca7:f47b:94c2/64 via 2001:db8:: dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: No such process

Comment: There is no default route in your routing table, so nothing to remove. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ok.my mistake .sorry every one